# fullcalendar json feed start times?

Tags: json, fullcalendar

is it possible to display start & end times on full calendar latest version? I am using json to feed the data as such, this works fine:

```
// Initializes a container array for all of the calendar events
$jsonArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
 $id = $row['HolidayType'];
 $title = $row['name'];
 $start = $row['start'];
 $end = $row['end'];
 // Stores each database record to an array
 $buildjson = array('title' => "$title", 'start' => "$start", 'end' => "$end", 'allDay' => false);
 // Adds each array into the container array
 array_push($jsonArray, $buildjson);
}

echo json_encode($jsonArray);
```

In my db I added 2 columns, start_time & end_time, if I add those to above code it doesnt pull times through and page errors?

```
// Initializes a container array for all of the calendar events
$jsonArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
 $id = $row['HolidayType'];
 $title = $row['name'];
 $start = $row['start'];
 $end = $row['end'];
 $start_time = $row['start_time'];
 $end_time = $row['end_time'];

 // Stores each database record to an array
 $buildjson = array(
 'title' => "$title",
 'start' => "$start",
 'end' => "$end",
 'start_time' => "$start_time",
 'end_time' => "$end_time",
 'allDay' => false);
 // Adds each array into the container array
 array_push($jsonArray, $buildjson);
}

echo json_encode($jsonArray);
```

Any ideas how I would pull the time through via json, using start_tim, end_time is obviously incorrect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gary, do your start and end params not contain times? Out of the box Fulcalendar will display the start time using the default timeFormat:'h(:mm)t' which if you look at the example demos on FulCalendar's site show as 7p or 10:30a for example. You do need to use allDay:false for this to happen.

As for showing both start and end dates. I could not find anything that would do that directly out the box. I ended up modifying the code (somewhere around line 4700 for the month display and got the event block to display solething like this...

**07:00** *title* **10:30**

If your start and end params don't contain time the you should be able to use the extra values in your array by using event.start_time and event.end_time, but again you will need to modify the main FulCalendar.js

If you need any more info let me know.

Comment: Hi there, many thanks for your reply. I think I may be confused a little. When I use datepicker to add start/end dates it inserts for example 2012-03-08 00:00:00 in the mysql 'datetime' field. I added my start/end time fields because I wanted to set the time is that not the best method to do this? How do you insert a time into the datetime field with extra columns?

Thanks again..

Comment: Ok, when I make up a form I use a datepicker plus either a single drop down if the scope is small enough e.g. 6:30, 7:00 7:30 etc. or a couple of drop downs one for hours and the other for mins. In .net I would normally have this as a user control and the have two of these one for setting the start and the other for end times. Once submitted the code behind will take the combined information the date, hour and min and store this as one complete datetime. So basically all you need to do is instead of saving the start time sepreately combine it to the date and then save to your start field. HTH.